# jQuery valid() method causes all errors to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, paypal

I am trying to use jquery validation to unhide a paypal button when the form is valid. I am using the `valid()` method as shown below. The problem is, that as soon as one key is pressed in any of the form elements, all of the errors show. How can I check if it's valid without firing all of errors?

```
$('#jValidate').validate({
  rules:{
    username:{
      required:true,
      minlength:6
    },
    email:{
      required:true,
      email:true
    },    
    password:{
      required:true,
      minlength:8
    },
    confirm:{
      required:true,      
      equalTo:"#password"
    }    
  },
  messages:{
    username:{
      required:"Username is required",
      minLength:"Username must be at least 6 characters"
    },
    password:{
      required:"Password is required",
      minLength:"Password must be at least 8 characters"
    },
    confirm:{
      required:"You must confirm your password",
      equalTo:"Password Confirmation does not match"
    }
  }
});
$('#jValidate .form-control').keyup(function(){
  if($('#jValidate').valid()){
    $('#signup').show();
    $('#disabled').hide();  
  }
});
```

Comment: That is expected behavior when you run `valid()` on whole form. What is the question?

Comment: I want to check the form to see if it's valid and show content when it is.

Comment: Well that depends on behavior you want which you haven't explained.

Comment: I thought it was quite obvious. On keyup, when the form is valid, show one thing and hide another.

Answer (score 0):

```
var validator = $('#jValidate').validate({...rules, options});

validator.checkForm() // true if valid, false if not.
```

Comment: That checks the form after each keyup and triggers the error before the user is done typing. For instance, if the `minlength=6` the user gets an error right away before he gets to 6.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/veviqayiru/edit?html,js,output

see options: onfocusout: false, onkeyup: false. That's not only .valid triggers all the validation.